# How to handle a double click on covalent datatable

Tags: angular, teradata-covalent

I recently started using Teradata covalent datatable after giving up on getting angular/material datatable to work...  I am trying to handle a double click on a specific row of the datatable but have no idea where to start.  How can I access the row data and then add a (dblclick) output to it if the table is mostly6 defined in typescript?

```
my code:

my html:

<td-data-table #dataTable [data]="filteredEmployees" [columns]="columns" [sortable]="true" [sortBy]="sortBy" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" (sortChange)="sort($event)"></td-data-table> 

my typescript:

import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

import { TdDataTableService, TdDataTableSortingOrder, ITdDataTableSortChangeEvent, ITdDataTableColumn } from '@covalent/core';
import { IPageChangeEvent } from '@covalent/core';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { IEmployee } from '../../interfaces/employee.interface';

import { StringToDatePipe } from '../../pipes/string-to-date.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cashier-maintenance',
  templateUrl: './cashier-maintenance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cashier-maintenance.component.css']
})
export class CashierMaintenanceComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('filterTbl') filterTbl: ElementRef;
    employees: IEmployee[];
    filteredEmployees: IEmployee[];
    filteredTotal: number = 100;
  columns: ITdDataTableColumn[] = [
  { name: 'EMP_ID', label: 'ID', sortable: true, width: 100 },
  { name: 'EMP_NM', label: 'Name', sortable: true, width: 200 },
  { name: 'EMP_TYP', label: 'Type', sortable: true, width: 200 },
  { name: 'TEL', label: 'Telephone', sortable: true, width: 200 },
  { name: 'ADDR', label: 'Address', sortable: true, width: 200 },
  { name: 'DT_STRT', label: 'Start Date', sortable: false, width: 200 }
];
searchTerm: string = '';
sortBy: string = 'EMP_NM';
fromRow: number = 1;
currentPage: number = 1;
pageSize: number = 10;
  sortOrder: TdDataTableSortingOrder = TdDataTableSortingOrder.Ascending;



  constructor(private _dataTableService: TdDataTableService, private restService: RestService)  { }

    sort(sortEvent: ITdDataTableSortChangeEvent): void {
        this.sortBy = sortEvent.name;
        console.log(sortEvent.name);
        this.filter();
    }

    search(searchTerm: string): void {
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
        this.filter();
    }

    page(pagingEvent: IPageChangeEvent): void {
        this.fromRow = pagingEvent.fromRow;
        this.currentPage = pagingEvent.page;
        this.pageSize = pagingEvent.pageSize;
        this.filter();
    }

    filter(): void {
        let newData: IEmployee[] = this.employees;
        let excludedColumns: string[] = this.columns
            .filter((column: ITdDataTableColumn) => {
                return ((column.filter === undefined && column.hidden === true) ||
                (column.filter !== undefined && column.filter === false));
            }).map((column: ITdDataTableColumn) => {
            return column.name;
        });
    newData = this._dataTableService.filterData(newData, this.searchTerm, true, excludedColumns);
    this.filteredTotal = newData.length;
    newData = this._dataTableService.sortData(newData, this.sortBy, this.sortOrder);
    newData = this._dataTableService.pageData(newData, this.fromRow, this.currentPage * this.pageSize);
    this.filteredEmployees = newData;
  }






  getEmployees() {
      this.restService.getEmployees() 
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        console.log(res);       
        this.employees = res;
        this.employees.forEach((emp: IEmployee) => {
            emp.DT_STRT = new StringToDatePipe().transform(emp.DT_STRT);
        });
        this.filter();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
         Observable.fromEvent(this.filterTbl.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .debounceTime(150)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.searchTerm = this.filterTbl.nativeElement.value;
          this.filter();
        });

      this.getEmployees();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the Teradata Covalent data table does not support the doubleclick event. The team recommends using a button or icon for secondary actions. This is because double clicking is a desktop pattern that does not translate well to mobile devices.

See [Teradata/covalent#813](https://github.com/Teradata/covalent/issues/813) for a discussion on the data table double click event.

Comment: could you please add a link to or a small example of using an action button with the table?  i'm quite confused as to how I can go about that as the table is mostly defined in the ts/component code?

Comment: Also I am unable to use the atomic components as I need sorting/filtering/pagination on the table.

Comment: The first example on the [data table docs](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/data-table) uses a button. You should be able to mark any sortable columns as such in the template.

Comment: Doesn't that example use the atomic components?  As far as I understood filtering/sorting/pagination isn't possible when using the atomic components?